# Snowflake/Snowsight dashboard custom filters cannot select desired values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have many dashboards that require a user to filter to on a specific ID in our database. We have billions of IDs to select from but Snowsight will only all us to display 10,000 fields in the drop down for selection.

Is there any way that we can just paste in the ID and run rather than having to find and select? We'll never be able to write a filter query that'll dynamically cover all bases.

select id from table

Snowsight gives a warning that only 10,000 rows can be shown so I tried hard-typing the ID in the filter option and nothing happens. It forces you to either select an ID shown (the one I want isn't in the list of 10,000) or the "All" option.

Answer (score 0):

In snowflake query editor you should be able to enter query, and use a where clause for filtering.
e.g. select id from table where id=1;